# Using IN operator with pg_prepare

Tags: php, sql, postgresql, postgresql-9.1, postgresql-9.0

I would like to use pg_prepare with the IN operator

```
SELECT id FROM people WHERE name IN $1;
```

I'd also like to use it with postgres arrays, I can't seem to get either to work and am unable to find it in the documentation.

Thanks for your help,

Mark

Comment: Well not finding the documentation might be the cause of not getting it to work. Please contact the vendor of that software for your support options to obtain the documentation. Per this sites on-hold reasons: Questions asking us to **recommend or find a tool, library or favorite off-site resource** are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, [describe the problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/139399/) and what has been done so far to solve it. - I consider the documentation you ask for as an off-site resource.

Comment: The on-hold is not deserved. He didn't say he can't find the documentation. He says he can't find it **in** the documentation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here they speak about what you are looking for : http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.pg-prepare.php#62675

```
$result = pg_prepare($dbconn, "my_query", 'SELECT id FROM people WHERE name IN($1,$2,$3)'); 
$result = pg_execute($dbconn, "my_query", array("foo", "bar", "test"));
```

Comment: this sounds rather like a comment than an answer - please keep comments as comments, don't put them into answers.

Comment: The link provided was to one of many comments, rather than an official bit of documentation. However it still provided the answer.